# clang vs gcc run-time difference: c++ class template built w clang crashes w/o copy constructor, built w gcc crashes with copy constructor

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, copy-constructor

Would does the following code crash during run-time when built with clang (but not gcc) unless I include a copy constructor for the `TableTypeCarrier` template class? If I include that copy constructor why do I experience the same run-time crash when built with gcc?

I have the following c++ classes defined:

```
class TableTypeCarrierBase {};

template<class T>
class TableTypeCarrier: public TableTypeCarrierBase {
public:
    TableTypeCarrier(const T * const p) : m_p(p) {}

#ifdef __clang__
    TableTypeCarrier(const TableTypeCarrier<T>& o) : m_p(o.m_p) {}
#endif

    const T * Get() const
    {
      return m_p;
    }

private:
    const T * const m_p;
};

struct PsiTable {
    PsiTable() : m_priv(NULL) { }

    template<typename T> void Set(const TableTypeCarrier<T> inT)
    {
      m_priv = &inT;
    }

    template<typename T> const T * Get() const
    {
      return (!m_priv) ? NULL : ((TableTypeCarrier<T>*)m_priv)->Get(); 
    }

private:
    const TableTypeCarrierBase *m_priv;
};
```

You'll notice that the copy constructor of the `TableTypeCarrier` class template is conditionalized to only be built by clang and not gcc.

While writing this code originally (without the above conditionalized copy constructor), I was only using gcc to build and test it.  When I tried to test it built with clang, the build would always succeed, but there would be a run-time crash while manipulating objects of these classes.

I spent months debugging this.  I don't exactly recall the path that led me to try adding a copy constructor to the `TableTypeCarrier` template class, but indeed that solved the problem with my binaries built using clang.  Unfortunately, simply having this copy constructor declared seemed to cause the same problem as originally described, but only when built using gcc.

Naturally, I added precompiler directives to conditionalize the copy constructor only if built using clang.

This fix worked for me, but I want to understand why.

If you need context to fully understand the problem, here is a link to the header that defines these classes within the full project at a point in history when this exact code was still present:

https://github.com/mkrufky/libdvbtee/blob/v0.4.0/libdvbtee/decode/table/table.h

I have since refactored the code and removed the `TableTypeCarrierBase` class and `TableTypeCarrier` template classes alltogether, as these were unnecessary proxies.  Despite removing this code, I still want to understand why binaries built with clang vs binaries built with gcc behave differently when `TableTypeCarrier` has (or lacks) a copy constructor.

Why does a clang-built binary require this copy constructor?  Why does a gcc-built binary crash if I include it?

Comment: Are you sure you hade no undefined behavior anywhere else in your code? I think that no one except you can say this, unless you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can provide (apart from the github link) to make my example more complete :-/  Any other code that uses these classes would be too much to paste into this question post, in my opinion.

Comment: You should not just provide some additional code. You should _make_ an MCVE, which means _removing_ extra code unless you are absolutely sure nothing more can be removed.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  This will help me ask better questions in the future.  However, somebody has already found a problem with the code that *might* lead to the answer to my question, so I'm hoping the question doesn't get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a problem here:

```
template<typename T> void Set(const TableTypeCarrier<T> inT)
{
  m_priv = &inT;
}
```

You are passing the argument by value (and hence making a copy of it), but then you are taking the address of it and assigning it to a member variable.  When the function ends, the object you took the address of disappears leaving a dangling pointer.

A compiler on a suitably high warning level should flag this.

Comment: That's a good catch.  I'm not sure if it explains the difference in behavior between gcc and clang, but it's definitely something that I'll fix right away.

Comment: Your TableStore::add function looks fishy also.  But I can't see the complete implementation.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the code in https://github.com/mkrufky/libdvbtee/blob/v0.4.0/libdvbtee/decode/table/table.cpp ?

Comment: I can't tell.  But it would depend on what you do with the local variables you create inside the add function in your subsequent function calls.  Keep in mind those local variable disappear when the add function ends.

Comment: A PsiTable object is passed into a constructor of a LinkedTable<T>.  All of the work on the incoming data (inside that PsiTable) is processed in this constructor, and the PsiTable (along with its private internal pointer) are never used again outside of the LinkedTable<T> constructor.  This LinkedTable<T> constructor copies the data that it needs and never touches the PsiTable source again.

Comment: I should have some time over the next few days to roll back to this older version of my code and fix the dangling reference.  As I mentioned, I had already removed this code block some time ago, but was still curious why this happens.  If it sheds light on the difference in behavior between clang and gcc builds, then I'll accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem!  After changing the argument to `Set()` to pass by reference, the crash disappears when built with clang, and the functionality is the same regardless of whether the copy constructor is present, regardless of whether built by glang or gcc.  Thank you - this indeed was the answer.